# Hookup new Picturebox Paint Event

Tags: vb.net, class, events, picturebox

I'm new to events so be gentle. Basically I'm trying to Paint a .gif onto a picturebox and add it to a flowlayout panel. The reason for this is that the gif keeps looping if I don't count the frames and paint it.

Basically I've created the picturebox within a single class, and I want to hook up the paint event, and have the paint event fire when the class is newed up in the main form class. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, maybe this isn't best practice or maybe someone can suggest a better way of doing it. Currently when I call the class form the main form, the class variables are steped through, but I never see the picturebox that I've declared "withevents" get stepped to. Also the Paint event is never stepped into either. Please see my code below

```
    Public Class CompleteMark
    Implements IDisposable

    Dim WithEvents _picBox As PictureBox

#Region "VARIABLES"

    'Disposable variables
    Private managedResource As System.ComponentModel.Component
    Private unmanagedResource As IntPtr
    Protected disposed As Boolean = False

    'Class Variables
    Dim _cm As New Bitmap(My.Resources.cmt)
    Dim _currentlyAnimating As Boolean = False
    Dim _frameCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim _frameCount As Integer
    Dim _frameDim As Imaging.FrameDimension


    '_picBox  = New PictureBox()




#End Region

    Sub New(ByVal flp As FlowLayoutPanel)
        _picBox = New PictureBox()
        _picBox.Size = New Size(14, 13)
        _picBox.Margin = New Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)
        _picBox.Name = "AnimCheckMark"
        _picBox.Image = _cm
        flp.Controls.Add(_picBox)
        _picBox.Invalidate()

        'AddHandler _picBox.Paint, AddressOf AnimCheckMark_Paint

    End Sub

    Private Sub OnFrameChanged(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        _picBox.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AnimateImage()
        If Not _currentlyAnimating Then
            ImageAnimator.Animate(_cm, New EventHandler(AddressOf OnFrameChanged))
            _currentlyAnimating = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub AnimCheckMark_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles _picBox.Paint
        _frameDim = New Imaging.FrameDimension(_cm.FrameDimensionsList(0))
        _frameCount = _cm.GetFrameCount(_frameDim)

        If _frameCounter < _frameCount Then
            AnimateImage()
            ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames()
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_cm, New Point(0, 0))
            _frameCounter += 1
        End If
    End Sub

#Region " IDisposable Support "

    Protected Overridable Overloads Sub Dispose(
            ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposed Then
            If disposing Then
                managedResource.Dispose()
            End If
            ' Add code here to release the unmanaged resource.
            unmanagedResource = IntPtr.Zero
            ' Note that this is not thread safe. 
        End If
        Me.disposed = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub AnyOtherMethods()
        If Me.disposed Then
            Throw New ObjectDisposedException(Me.GetType().ToString,
                    "This object has been disposed.")
        End If
    End Sub


    ' Do not change or add Overridable to these methods. 
    ' Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean). 
    Public Overloads Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        Dispose(False)
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

Then I new this class with a test button on the main form:

```
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    Dim chkMark As CompleteMark
    chkMark = New CompleteMark(flpAdobeLbl)
End Sub
```

The picturebox is created on the form and the .gif shows up but no animation. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops! Solved it, the code above works fine for hooking up to an Event. I just stupidly hadn't set a breakpoint in the event handler so VS wasn't stepping into it.

Apparently VS will only step into event handlers if there is a breakpoint.